# LESS: height & width percentage to pixels, and adding them up

Tags: less, percentage

In Less I have these defined:

```
@height-5: (@winheight / 100) * 5;
@height-10: (@winheight / 100) * 10;
...etc
```

`@winheight` comes from:

```
@winheight:`$(window).height()`;
```

(Same for width)

Now I can use:

```
width: ~"@{width-10}px";
height: ~"@{height-100}px";
```

To set the window's `percentage` as `pixels`.

But now I want to calculate a height and width like:

```
left: @width-80 + @height-10 + "px";
```

Or:

```
left: ~"@{width-80 + @height-10}px";
```

The first one doesn't work because it puts a space between the `value` and `px`

The second one does not compile, I've tried some variations, but no luck.

.

Second problem is I want to make a function out of it, rather than defining each percentage, I tried this:

```
.winheight (@percentage){
   height: (@winheight / 100) * @percentage;
}
```

But when I try this inside some class:

```
.winheight(10)
```

I get an error
Basically what I would want is just return a value somehow, like:

```
@win_height_perc(@perc):  (@winheight / 100) * @perc;
```

Instead of having to define a seperate function for `height:`, `width:`, `top:`, `left:`

(I'm updating on `$(window).resize` with `less.watch()` to update the pixel/percentages btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your first problem, you could use:

```
left: @width-80 + @height-10 + 0px;
```

or

```
left: unit(@width-80 + @height-10, px);
```

What error do you get when you call your `.winheight` mixin? It should work fine (at least with static variables defined inside a Less stylesheet). It might fail depending on other factors, since your `@winheight` depends on a dynamic DOM value (access to the DOM is not guaranteed). In any case, you should call it with a `%` unit, if you want it to be treated as a percentage:

```
.winheight(100%)
```

In Less 1.7 this *will* compile:

```
left: ~"@{width-80 + @height-10}px"
```

But will simply print the string generating invalid CSS:

```
left: @{width-80 + @height-10}px
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the error was about the space between the value and px, but `*1px` works, and i guess similarly `+0px` works, because then LESS just makes it a `px` value. (The problem with using % on some elements, that the behaviour will break, so I rather dynamically generate pixel values. Although I think %values shouldn't change elements' behaviours, and be handled by the browser properly..)